# Consistent unknown and fatal error in R / RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio, fatal-error

Is there any way I can find out what happened that results into a crash?
I tried running a script multiple times now, and it seems to crash after a **random** amount of work done.

This is what I get (R studio):
 [image]

As you can see, this isn't of any help.

As for memory: I am trying to construct a matrix with 34 million entries.
I monitored the memory usage during execution and came to the conclusion that there wasn't a big increase in memory. Memory was constant-ish at about 580mb.

The crash only occurs in R studio. Not in the R interpreter.

Comment: which rstudio version you are using?

Comment: @grubjesic Version 0.99.465 with R version 3.2.1

Comment: ok, so rstudio and R version seems fine.  Can we maybe see the script and data so I can try to reproduce this error?

Comment: It's probably an error in compiled code in a package you're using. It would help to have the stack trace and/or core dump (I'm not sure how to get either from RStudio), and the output from `sessionInfo()`.

Comment: Does this cause problems if you run the script using the R GUI?

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich The code works fine in the R interpreter, the crash only occurs when executing in the R studio environment